# Usage of the present perfect in talking about a past event

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

This was sent from a native speaker so I assume his sentence to be correct.

> I've been to Dublin for a weekend and loved it.

If that's not the case, please tell me. I just don't understand the use of the present perfect in the first section. Shouldn't it be "I was in Dublin for a weekend and loved it" because it's completely over?

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

**Have you ever been to Dublin?

-- Yes, I have been to Dublin.**

The present perfect can be used to speak of those past events which have some bearing upon the present. In this case, a weekend spent in Dublin is now among the speaker's experiences.

But if the speaker wishes to talk about what Dublin was like during the time that he was there, that is, about events that transpired entirely in the past, and don't really have any bearing upon the present, the simple past tense is good:

**That weekend I spent in Dublin was rainy.**

Comment: +1 Perzackly. Context is also important: a present perfect may be used to shift a discussion from present to past.